# Logback: do I rebuild logback for custom layouts?

Tags: logback

I created a custom layout (as shown in Chapter 6: Layouts, http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html), so do I have to patch logback, or there is a configurable way to let logback knows about my custom layout class?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference your layout in logback.xml by using the full namespace of your custom layout. So if your layout is at `com.mydomain.logback.layouts.MyCustomLayout` then in your logback.xml, you'd have an appender definition that looks something like this:

`<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="com.mydomain.logback.layouts.MyCustomLayout" />
    </appender>`

Now every time a log event gets passed through the STDOUT appender, it will be processed by your custom appender. No need to recompile Logback.